# change z-index of hover background

Tags: css, hover, background-image, z-index

Is this possible? I've got

```
<div class="one">
  <a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></a>
</div>
```

I want it so on hover of the div (or `<a>`) the new hover:background color/image covers the `<img>`, kind of like the z-index of the hover changes.

So in this fiddle on hover of the `<div>` or `<a>` the 100px img wouldn't be visible, everything would be gold.

http://jsfiddle.net/q9Fm3/2/

I'd like to keep the inline `<img>` element.

Comment: I've tried z-index on the `<div>`, `<a>`, and `<img>` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A background image can't be on top of an image in the same element, but you can simulate what you want by adding:

```
.one:hover img {
    display:none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q9Fm3/3/)**

Comment: Is there any way to get the bg image on top of the element?

Comment: @user2118228 That kind of violates the idea of what a background image does.  The functionality you are looking for probably requires the background image to be a normal img.  Otherwise, this answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this rule:

```
.one:hover img {display:none;}
```